# I can't get the JQuery fading permalink to to show up on my posts

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm making a Tumblr theme and this is the code I got from another Tumblr blog.

```
    div.fade {
    display: none;
}
```

And for the JQuery.

```
<script>
//JQuery Fader code
$(document).ready(function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
    // Slow can be any number of ms
    $("div.fade").fadeIn('slow', function () {
        // Do nothing
        });
    }, 2000); // Fade in after 2000 ms (2 secs)
});
</script>
```

Here's the fade div.

```
<div class="fade">
<a href="{Permalink}"><time datetime="{TimeAgo}">{TimeAgo}</time>&nbsp;/&nbsp;

{block:NoteCount}<a class="notecount" href="{Permalink}#notes">{NoteCountWithLabel}</a>{/block:NoteCount}&nbsp;/&nbsp;

{block:ContentSource}
<a href="{SourceURL}">{lang:Source}:{block:NoSourceLogo}{SourceTitle}{/block:NoSourceLogo}</a>&nbsp;/&nbsp;
{/block:ContentSource} 

<div class="my-like" data-reblog="{ReblogURL}" data-id="{PostID}" title="Like">&hearts;</div>&nbsp;/&nbsp;

<a href=”{ReblogURL}” target=”_blank”>{ReblogButton size="15"}</a>
</div>
```

Is there anyway I can get it to work properly?

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8vnR4/

Comment: What are you trying to make it do? Put a JSFiddle on for you: http://jsfiddle.net/8vnR4/

Comment: There is nothing wrong with that code http://jsfiddle.net/mE9cF/.  Maybe you're not including jQuery?

Comment: Actually I solved the problem by changing it to position: absolute; with CSS. Thanks.